# how to get the default vibration pattern of an android device?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-vibration

I am creating an app for Android API 23, and I want to get the default vibration pattern that is used when the phone rings?

I have this so far:

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
long[] pattern = {0, 500, 1000}; // default pattern goes here
vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

How can I get the default pattern?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default vibrate pattern can be found at the following class: `com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java`, which is

```
static final long[] DEFAULT_VIBRATE_PATTERN = {0, 250, 250, 250};
```

See the source code from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#343).

Unfortunately, there is no public API to get this default pattern so far.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the default vibrate pattern is a

```
{ delay, vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep } pattern
```

In case of your code

```
long[] pattern = new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 };
```

The vibration now set to a delay of 1000 ms. If you set the first one to 0, it will go off instantly.

Comment: i want to get it programmatically, is there some sort of API that can do that?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but thanks for explaining the meaning behind the pattern values. That helped me with another issue I had!

Comment: Thanks for explaining the pattern